# What is the use of GFP_USER flag in kmalloc?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kmalloc

As far as I understand, the use in the `GFP_USER` flag (in the call to `kmalloc`) is used to allocate memory for user space. Does it means that the allocated page are in kernel space, which are accessible to user?
Does these pages required to be `mmapp`'ed in user space or the address is directly accessible to user.
If they need to `mmapp` then what is difference between `GFP_USER` and `GFP_KERNEL`?

Answer (score 5):

Brief explanation can be found in kernel [sources](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/43cb5d49a99b3ecd9fef9826899aac948c3048da/include/linux/gfp.h#L245):

> `GFP_KERNEL` is typical for kernel-internal allocations. The caller
> requires ZONE_NORMAL or a lower zone for direct access but can direct
> reclaim.
>
> `GFP_USER` is for userspace allocations that also need to be directly
> accessibly by the kernel or hardware. It is typically used by hardware
> for buffers that are mapped to userspace (e.g. graphics) that hardware
> still must DMA to. cpuset limits are enforced for these allocations.

```
#define GFP_KERNEL      (__GFP_RECLAIM | __GFP_IO | __GFP_FS)
#define GFP_USER        (__GFP_RECLAIM | __GFP_IO | __GFP_FS | __GFP_HARDWALL)
```

From [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/43cb5d49a99b3ecd9fef9826899aac948c3048da/include/linux/gfp.h#L96):

> __GFP_HARDWALL enforces the [cpuset](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cpusets.txt) memory allocation policy.